# Give a class of "selected" when clicked on another <a> then remove the class if it's the same <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change

```
$('h2 a').on('click', function(){
    $('h2 a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I made an Accordion, the first tab has class `selected`. So when I click on another tab, it removes `selected` class from the first tab and gives the one I clicked on `selected`, if I click on the same tab I just opened, it removes `selected`.

Comment: I think it's the same <a>,because this <a> tag object not changed in memory.just <a> tag attribute changed.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.is()`, `.filter()`

```js
var h2 = $("h2 a");

h2.on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(".selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    h2.removeClass("selected")
      .filter(this).addClass("selected")
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h2>
<a>a</a>
<a>b</a>
<a>c</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below answer, add one class in h2 tag so it not work for other h2 tag. when you click any just remove "**selected**" class and add "**selected**" class in current element.

Html:

```
<h2 class="headerTitle">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Headeing1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Headeing2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Headeing3</a>
</h2>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.headerTitle a').on('click', function(){
        jQuery('.headerTitle a').removeClass('selected');
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{ color: red; }
</style>
```