# if clicked on another element remove class with react

Tags: css, reactjs

Currently upgrading from a jquery / php webapp to react. All is going well and I understand the concepts behind react etc. The only issue I can't find a workaround is how to dynamically add / delete a class based on where the user clicks. I need this because I have a few dropdowns which trigger when the user click it and need to be hidden if they click somewhere else.

From:  [Give a class of "selected" when clicked on another <a> then remove the class if it's the same <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239492/give-a-class-of-selected-when-clicked-on-another-a-then-remove-the-class-if)

I've taken this example as it is simple, Jquery solution to the problem:

```
var h2 = $("h2 a");

h2.on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(".selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    h2.removeClass("selected")
      .filter(this).addClass("selected")
  }
});
```

**How to mimic the same functionality in react (and / or redux)?**

Image to further clarify
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, you want to toggle some data on click event and change the classname of a html element accordingly.

Your data that 'selected' class based on could come from anywhere, from parent or component state. You would do something like this :

```
<div className={ myData ? 'selected' : '' } ></div>
```

But there is a better way to display classname changes with a library called classnames. The same thing is accomplished as :

```
<div className={ classNames({ 'selected' : myData }) } ></div>
```

Until now, we have seen how to display changes on render function. Second thing you need is to listen to click events and fire the function that will eventually toggle the data that controls the 'selected' classname, in my example 'myData'.

Here is a working example, there might be various ways to accomplish this. But I strongly recommend using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library to toggle classnames.

The workaround about removing class when another element ( apart from li elements we observe ) clicked could be solved by a click event listener.

```
For instance : 

import React, { Component }     from 'react'
import classNames               from 'classnames'

class DropDown extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeSelected : ''
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    global.document.addEventListener( 'click', this.handleClick, false )
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    global.document.removeEventListener( 'click', this.handleClick, false )
  }
  handleClick(event){
    if( event.target.className.includes('not-changing-css-class') && 
        this.state.activeSelected !== '' 
    ) this.setState( { activeSelected : '' } )
  }
  render(){
    let { activeSelected } = this.state
    return (
      <ul>
        <li 
          className={ classNames({
            'not-changing-css-class' : true,
            'selected' : activeSelected === 'item1'
          }) } 
          onClick={ event => this.setState({ activeSelected : activeSelected === 'item1' ? '' : 'item1' }) }
        >
          Item 1
        </li>
        <li 
          className={ classNames({
            'not-changing-css-class' : true,
            'selected' : activeSelected === 'item2'
          }) } 
          onClick={ event => this.setState({ activeSelected : activeSelected === 'item2' ? '' : 'item2' }) }
        >
          Item 2
        </li>
        <li 
          className={ classNames({
            'not-changing-css-class' : true,
            'selected' : activeSelected === 'item3'
          }) } 
          onClick={ event => this.setState({ activeSelected : activeSelected === 'item3' ? '' : 'item3' }) }
        >
          Item 3
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: wll this also remove the `selected` class if the user clicks elsewhere (aka not on one of those 3 items)?

Comment: What do you mean ? These toggling will happen only if someone clicks on li elements in my code.

Comment: I understand, but what if they click on another element on the page? The dropdown will still have the class `selected`. They will need to close it manually and that is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Will this work if I have more then one place where I will implement this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130309/discussion-between-nealvdv-and-furkano).

Comment: Please also correct classname to className, otherwise logs error undefined

Comment: Probably not best to use `event.target.className.includes()` to check if the element has a class, because it would return true for something like `button` as well as `buttonSelected`. Better to use `event.target.classList.contains()`

Comment: Hi Furkan can you please this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58040667/2479903

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the selected element index (or ID if you use IDs) in the component state. You can use redux store if you think this state will be relevant to any other component in your app, but starting with state is simpler.

Once you have this state. You can check within your `render()` function whether a link is selected or not, by comparing with the component state. You would also update the selectedIndex whent the links are clicked.

A simple example to render the links could be as follows. Note that you can extract parts of these to be functions instead of using expressions in JSX.

```

```
allLinks.map( (link, index) => 
  <a href={link.target} className={this.state.selectedIndex === index ? 'selected' : null}/>
)
```

```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be clever to use map() to create all your links as some can obviously be created by an ajax call or so.

Comment: Not sure about your app, but if you don't want to use map, you can go ahead with a `data-` attribute or ID instead of an index to hold in the state mentioned in the answer.